# Router Angular multiple views groups

Tags: angular, typescript, routes

what is the correct approach to work two groups of views in Angular? Let's see if I explain, in a common web what I usually do in `app.component.html` is:

```
<app-header></app-header>
<router-outlet></router-outlet>
<app-footer></app-footer>
```

With this always the `app-header` and `the app-footer` will be repeated.

But what happens if I want to have another group of views, for example if I want to implement an intranet, something like the image:

[image]
How should I implement this?

For example, this is what I currently have, how would I get `queHacemosAdminComponent` to be in another group of views?

```js
const rutas: Routes = [
 { path: '', component: InicioComponent },
 { path: 'queHacemos', component: QueHacemosComponent },
 { path: 'contacto', component: ContactoComponent },
 { path: 'queHacemosAdmin', component: QueHacemosAdminComponent }
]
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You just need an additional level of routing:

```
const routes = [
  { 
    path: '', 
    component: Group1Component // contains header1, footer1 and router-outlet
    children: [
      { path: '', component: InicioComponent },
      { path: 'queHacemos', component: QueHacemosComponent },
      { path: 'contacto', component: ContactoComponent }
    ]
  },
  { 
    path: '', 
    component: Group2Component // contains header2, footer2 and router-outlet
    children: [
      { path: 'queHacemosAdmin', component: QueHacemosAdminComponent }
    ]
  }
];
```

Comment: It worked! thanks for explaining a correct approach.